# I want to charge a tablet that requires 5V / 3A power input in the field with a powerbank. The tablet uses a 3.5mm / 1.3mm DC barrel plug

Tags: usb, tablet, charging, portable

I have a 45w PD portable charger that has 1 USB Type C output at 45W, DC 5V/3A, 9V/3A, 15V/3A, 20V/2.25A and 2 USB Type A outputs with DC 5V/3.4A Total, DC 5V/2.4A max each.

The tablet charges using a 5V 3A ∮3.5mm / 1.3mm power adapter.

Is this possible?  I am happy to purchase an adapter to go from the USB-C to the barrel plug if needed, but I can only find Type-A to barrel plug adapters.  Thanks

Comment: Please provide product exact specifiations

Comment: The most important question about this is: Is the original DC barrel positive or negative center? @Ramhound  It might work, albeit at trickle charge. Which is probably not what they intend.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options here:

1. Use the Type-C output. To use it you will need an adapter made of Type-C receptacle, and attach your 3.5/1.3 DC barrel plug to GND and VBUS. You will need to solder two 5.1k resistors between GND and CC1 and CC2 pins. The question is whether your charger outputs 3 A at 5V and therefore has 10k pull-ups on CC lines, or outputs only default 500/900 mA, and provides 3 A only after a PD contract is in place. Since your dongle won't have any PD, the standard Type-C power advertising must take precedence. So your success will depend on how your charger is designed.
2. Use Type-A ports, both of them, with a Y-cable, and forget the Type-C. It is likely that just one Type-A to DC barrel cable will work just fine, assuming that the Type-A port receptacle on your charger has enough quality to carry 3 A.